# Creating Flex 4.5 theme in Flash CS5

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I'm creating a theme for my project in flash professional CS5. In Flex 3, i had an option to create css file to import this theme. But how can i implement the same in Flex 4.5? Say, if i create a button design in flash, how shall i import that into flex 4.5 as a theme for button.

Comment: I can't answer the question, but I can tell you that the Spark (Flex4) skinning mechanism is completely different from the Halo (Flex3) styling system. Skins are created as MXML files. So you would need an option in CS5 that would export your Button design as MXML. I believe Catalyst could do this, but that product is no longer alive.